# Calendar Agenda view won't stay on today

Tags: calendar

I have the Optimus V.  I use Google calendar for all my calendaring needs.  I'm using the standard Calendar app that came with my phone, build 2.2.1.

I start the Calendar app, and go to Agenda view.  It's scrolled so that yesterday is the top.  Weird, I don't know why I'd care about my agenda for yesterday.  Any normal person would want to see today's agenda plus however much of tomorrow that fits.  So I go to menu->Today.  Now Today is at the top.  So far so good.

Now I go to menu->More->Settings, look at my settings and hit the back button.  Grrrr.  Yesterday is at the top again.  So I go to menu->Today.  Now Today is at the top again.

Now I hit the phone's power button.  Then I hit the power button again and unlock my phone.  Now the top entry in agenda is TWO DAYS ago, and today isn't shown at all.

Is there any way to prevent this extraordinarily irritating behavior?
I want "Today" to always be at the top of agenda view.  Not some completely random day.  Today.  Always Today.

Comment: Did you happen to have an event that started yesterday and finished today? Or perhaps a multi-day appointment?

Comment: Good theory, but no.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have seen similar behavior in the past. I cannot, however, duplicate it now.

Comment: good instincts re multi day events, al. that is indeed a bug that's been fixed upstream: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried "Business Calendar" which seems a lot less flaky and is free, so I guess the answer is to switch to another Calendar application.

Comment: Update: Business Calendar is no longer free now that it's out of beta. There's probably a decent free calendar app out there, but BC is worth the 6 bucks, IMO