# Google Calendar on Android opens to old date by default

Tags: google-calendar

When I open Google Calendar on my Android phone, it starts up showing October 1 2011. The phone knows the current date; pressing menu and then the today button goes to the correct day. I'd just like it to default to today like it did before 10/1. Any ideas?

This is Calendar 2.3.6, Android 2.3.6 GKR39F, on a Nexus s.

[This forum thread](http://androidforums.com/incredible-support-troubleshooting/237962-calendar-defaulting-old-date.html) seems to describe the same problem, but it's unresolved.

Comment: Similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/calendar-agenda-view-wont-stay-on-today

Comment: It's worse than that -- when I go to create a new appointment, the default date of the appointment is typically sometime last week.  As if I needed to remind myself to do something in the past.  Grr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this is a bug caused by agenda view and multi-day calendar entries. if you have one that includes the current day, calendar opens to the first day of that entry. fortunately, i think the bug is fixed upstream: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21605

simplest workaround is to delete the multi-day entry. :/