# Why does my calendar always open to the wrong date?

Tags: calendar

I'm using the native calendar app that came installed on my HTC Sensation. No matter which view I use (one day, week, month, or agenda) it always opens to a date about two weeks in the past. Even when creating new events, the initial date is incorrect.

I've seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/calendar-agenda-view-wont-stay-on-today), which isn't exactly the same as my issue, plus it's almost 2 years old.

I'd prefer not to have to use a third-party app for calendaring, and everything else about the calendar is fine (syncs correctly, displays multiple accounts' data.) It's just annoying to have to scroll through two weeks of data or date-picker tumblers to get to today.

Has anyone else run across this? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I'm running Froyo on a rooted (but not custom-rommed) phone.

Comment: Just wondering: The HTC Sensation is max. 1.5yrs old, it has been launched in 05/2011 (UK, US: 06/2011) and shipped with 2.3.3 Gingerbread, not 2.2 Froyo. See the [entry on gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_sensation-3875.php) for more. PS: It's officially upgradable to 4.0 ICS and an 4.1 JB update is also promised. If you dare you can S-Off it and install CyanogenMod 9.1 or 10. Maybe this fixes your calendar problem.

Comment: okay, i just wasn't logged in to stack exchange for android, just for stackexchange for stack overflow and code review. so now i can comment

Comment: have you tried another calendar app by chance to see if using two of the same shared calendar (like google calendar) will fix this?

Comment: @ce4 - you're right, it's gingerbread. I'm not interested in a custom rom right now - I used cyanogen on my old phone because I hated the interface, but I kind of like the Sense interface and don't want to change it. And it seems like a kind of drastic step just to fix a calendar display issue.

Comment: @DavidT. - no, I haven't tried another app. I don't want to add yet another app to my phone, and I don't know why you'd think having a separate app would fix the issue the native app is having.

Comment: @EmmyS well, i guess it probably wouldn't likely fix, but it's a good way to find out if your native is messed up, or that your calendar database/cursor is messed up. i didn't know you didn't want another calendar app. suggested as a "fix".

Comment: Emmy, you could still update to HTC's official 4.0 release without needing to mod. I just enumerated the options above and included CM10 for its relevance. Alas I'm out of other ideas as i don't have that model and debugging via logcat seems pointless here (app isn't crashing).

Comment: @ce4 - how do I update to htc's next release? I was under the impression that if you root your phone, you can't get the manufacturer's ota updates.

Comment: I don't think rooting means to lose ota functionality. this htc update might not be delivered ota also. Plus: no root afterwards. you have to re-root which might prove difficult with 4.0. Htc has/had a record of locking things up with updates. I don't know more alas, my latest model was an S-On pvt4 desire which was very hard to mod/root

Comment: *[user61456](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/61456/user61456) asks:* Do you have the correct date in your settings?

Comment: Seriously? Of course I had the correct date in my settings; if I hadn't I wouldn't have posted here, I'd have just fixed the date. This question is 18 months old, and I no longer have this phone, so please don't suggest that I just check to be sure.